# Meteor bug when selecting tex - document.getSelection().toString() returns empty string, same with window.getSelection().toString()

Tags: javascript, regex, meteor, selection, tostring

I have an issue..

I have div wrapped in another div.

`<div id="window-kitkat-wrap">
    {{{textDisplayKitkat}}}
  </div>`

`textDisplayKitkat` returns `return '<div id="window-kitkat" class="form-control" contenteditable="true">' + ((textDisplayKitkat) ? textDisplayKitkat : '') + '</div>';`

I have a function which uses regex on selected text.

Function fragment:

```
          var selection = document.getSelection();

  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    var selectionString = selection.toString(),
      choicesCleaned = selectionString.replace(/[(]*([a-zA-Z])[.)][.)]*([\w ,]*[ ])/g, "$1.$2 "),
      parent = getSelectionParentElement(),
      parentId = $(parent).attr('id');
console.log('parentId: ' + parentId);
console.log(selectionString);
console.log(choicesCleaned);
```

After selecting text and using this function - selectionString returns empty string, but parentId - 'window-kitkat-wrap'

When try the second time - select text and use the function - it all works! selectionString returns the selected text and parentId returns 'window-kitkat'

Same bug appears using window.getSelection()

Comment: What changes between the first and second try?

Comment: Nothing! I just reselect the same text.